# CSS или JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Постоянно задаюсь вопросом. CSS или JavaScript?? Если есть возможность сделать какой-то элемент на чистом css и не использовать js, то пользоваться этой возможностью ?

Comment: если есть насос, зачем надувать автопокрышку ртом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите на поддержку CSS-возможностей в браузерах. Это ключевой момент. В интернете полно решений вида "Слайдер на чистом CSS!", но, если он построен на возможностях CSS, которые не везде поддерживаются - использовать такое решение в продакшне не имеет смысла.

Изучайте код решений на CSS и проверяйте поддержку CSS-возможностей на [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com). Если поддержка вас устраивает - используйте решения на CSS. Иначе - JS.

Comment: Хорошо. А если у меня есть выпадающее меню ( построенное на js ), а в браузере отключен js, как оно будет адекватно работать ? Использовать modernizr и продумать два решения ?

Comment: Придерживайтесь progressive enhancement подхода. Замените выпадающее меню на ряд ссылок. Или расположите ссылки на отдельной странице, и обычной ссылкой ведите на эту страницу. А при загрузке ненавязчивого js меняйте переход на отдельную страницу на аяксовый запрос и вывод ссылок в выпадающем меню.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно! CSS - для вёрстки и дизайна, JS - для интерактивности. Бывают конечно исключения, когда нужен именно JS - но они редки, и связаны обычно с ультраспецифичностью фичи дизайна.

Comment: Допустим, создание слайдера ( просто прокрутка картинок, без кнопок ). Неужели так нужен JS если это можно сделать на css?Или Создание табов

Comment: @Илья Османов табы - нужен JS чтобы словить щелчок, в слайдере - словить щелчки кнопок. Там где есть слайдер без кнопок - там заказчик захочет слайдер с кнопками. Ну и вообще - нужны реакции на действия пользователя: безусловно JS - который манипулирует css-классами объектов. Если нужны просто красивости, без реакции от пользователя - конечно достаточно просто css. Использовать input:checkbox - для интерактивизации с помощью css - это костыль.

Comment: А почему костыль ? Я как раз за checkbox и думал

Comment: @Илья Османов захочется что-то сделать посложнее, поинтерактивнее: css уже не сможет это сделать, придётся переписывать - это раз.  На JS всё это делается проще и главное очевиднее - есить постулат, что код должен быть читаем: два. Не рекомендую шуруповёртом вбивать в стену гвозди короче)

Answer (score 0):

Ну смотрите:

`CSS` --> Стиль

`JavaScript` --> Логика

> Говорить о "`CSS` или `JavaScript`?" на мой взгляд немного не уместно,
>   т.к. они не могут заменить друг друга, а на оборот дополняют.

Единственное место где их можно сравнить это анимация, в которой выиграет `JavaScript` благодаря потреблению меньших ресурсов в 10-ти кратном размере:

[Доказательство](http://greensock.com/css-performance)

зы. Если решить проблему можно быстро на `CSS` используйте его, если нет то однозначно переходите к `JS`, не тратя свое время.